# How to use TreeStrategy in simpleframework

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I am using [simpleframework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) for deserializing xml hierarchical tree. I found that simpleframework has [TreeStrategy](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/strategy/TreeStrategy.html), but I can't find any samples. Have you any examples?

My XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SampleElem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Children>
      <SampleElem>
         <Children/>
         <Id>1</Id>
         <Value>Test2</Value>
      </SampleElem>
   </Children>
   <Id>-1</Id>
   <Value>Test1</Value>
</SampleElem>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you somehow? Not tested though ;)

**XML:**

```
<SampleElements name="example">
   <children>
      <SampleElement>
         <id>1</id>
         <value>Test1</value>
      </SampleElement>
      <SampleElement>
         <id>-1</id>
         <value>Test2</value>
      </SampleElement>
   </children>
</SampleElements>
```

**Java collection object:**

```
@Root
public class SampleElements {

   @ElementList
   private List<SampleElement> children;

   @Attribute
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public List getProperties() {
      return children;
   }
}

@Root
public class SampleElement {

   @Element
   private int id;

   @Element
   private String value;

   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }
}
```

Comment: My XML contains objects tree structure. Schema should allow to store relationships between parents and childrens. Your xml - simple list.